# <a href=link><div></a> link not woking

Tags: html, css

I have a row with some divs, and when the user clicks on those divs, I want them to be forwarded to another website. To do that I placed the `<a>` tag outside the `div` **like this:**

```html
<div class="row spacing2">
  <h3 id="Parceiros">Parceiros</h3>
  <a href="http://www.criticalsoftware.com/pt/homepage">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/CriticalSoftware.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.globalmediagroup.pt/">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/GlobalMedia.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pfrinvest/">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/pfr.jpg" style="height:100px;width:200px">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.planeta-virtual.pt/">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/PlanetaVirtual.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.sonae.pt/pt/">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/Sonae.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.agros.pt/">
    <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
      <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/Agros.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't know why, but when I inspect the element it says that my `a` tag is 0px x 0px. If someone can give me a tip I would appreciate it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should share with us your CSS code

Comment: HTML 5 states that the <a> element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".
HTML 4.01 specifies that <a> elements may only contain inline elements. A <div> is a block element, so it may not appear inside an <a>.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add col class outside of a tag.

```
<a href="http://www.criticalsoftware.com/pt/homepage"><div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/CriticalSoftware.png"></div></a>

<div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><a href="http://www.criticalsoftware.com/pt/homepage"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/CriticalSoftware.png"></a></div>
```

As col class has `float: left` property the a tag has 0 width and height.

Comment: even the <a> inside the div does not work, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css rule to your `<a>` tag:

```
display:block;
```